# How to center a div with dynamic content

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <button>First button</button>
  <button>Dynamically appear button</button>
<div>
```

I have a div which I want to be centered in two situation when it has one button and when it has 2 buttons.
Is there a way to do that ?

I created a fiddle for it 
http://fiddle.jshell.net/frqo0rsy/
I want that want I show the button the two buttons will be next each other and also centered.
I hope its more understood now.

Comment: You want to center the div and its content in respect to the body or center the content of the div in center of the div?

Comment: @Arber Braja it doesn't matter. I just added a fiddle so it could be more clearly

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the elements you want to center as `inline` or `inline-block` element and set `text-align: center` on the parent element.

```
button {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Updated your [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/frqo0rsy/2/).

There are other ways of doing this depending on what you are trying to achieve; the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div) question might help you.

Comment: Thanks @grim but i want the div to be one after another. I am not sure if it is possible cause in this case I should not put any width to the container div.

Comment: @barak You mean on the same line like this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/frqo0rsy/3/ ?

Comment: @barak or maybe just wrap the elements you want to center with a `div` or any other `block` element like the following: http://fiddle.jshell.net/frqo0rsy/4/

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I wanted I only knew to center div with margin: 0 auto; I don't really understand why people don't like my question

Comment: @barak Maybe because you weren't specific enough. In any case, glad to help.